# puppet generated systemd unit files using ERB templates?

Tags: puppet

I don't know how to structure my puppet code for systemd, for init.d I could easily configure multiple processes into a single file. But with unit file I don't have a clue on how do I do that as I need multiple pid files and multiple execstart and stops, can someone please help? I guess it could be done with [ERB templates](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.4/reference/lang_template_erb.html), but how do I do it? My unit file needs to look something like this or generate two separate unit files that could be used later, can somone help me on how puppet code should look like for such a case

```
[Unit]
Description=HEAD Search Service 
After=network.target

[Service]

Type=forking
PIDFile=/home/search_1/service/var/run/search/search.pid

ExecStart=/home/search_1/service/bin/search start
ExecStop=/home/search_1/service/bin/search stop

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description=HEAD Search Service 
After=network.target

[Service]

Type=forking
PIDFile=/home/search_2/service/var/run/search/search.pid

ExecStart=/home/logsearch_2/service/bin/searchstart
ExecStop=/home/logsearch_2/service/bin/search stop

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Notice the difference between both the unit files is just the directory structure, how can I write some puppet code to achieve this using templates ?

Comment: You can either template each unit file separately, or create an actual systemd template unit: https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/ You can then just replace the `search_X` bit with `%i`/`%I`.